# Map to MySQL at development stage

Tags: grails

I'm fairly new to grails, so I created an app and set it up to use mysql, installed the latest spring security RC4 plugin, and in the bootstrap.groovy set it to create a user and a role. Tables are created in the database but no data. Why is this happening?

Also, if I use the default datasource, tables are created but no data. Some errors are thrown but I read that it's a bug on the H4 version.

Anyway, I have set databases for dev and testing, and another for production and I would really like to use mysql because of data that I need to pull at the development stage.

//Edit
This is the code in BootStrap: The tutorial where I took this from seems to be in an older version perhaps 2.3.x, but it shouldn't be that different, I assume, right???

```
package com.ssdemo.auth

class BootStrap{
    def init = { serveletContext ->
        def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveWhere(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        def userInfo = User.findOrSaveWhere(username: 'admin', password: 'password')

        if(!userInfo.authorities.contains(adminRole)){
            UserRole.create(userInfo, adminRole, true)
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Any clues or pointers?

Comment: How about some more information? Like what version of grails and what the new entries in bootstrap.groovy look like.

Comment: Grails version is 2.4.3

Comment: the tutorial can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceN_I3kCF6s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug...

the problem is that I declared

```
package com.ssdemo.auth
```

instead of

```
import com.ssdemo.auth.*
```

Bootstrap now inserts the data to the database...